# Find the value of $\space\large i^{i^i}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Is $\large i^{i^i}$ real ? How to find it?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you know how to compute $i^i$? (P.S. I assume you want the principal value?)

Comment: $i^{i^i} = \cos \left( {\frac{1}{2}{e^{ - \pi /2}}\pi } \right) + i\sin \left( {\frac{1}{2}{e^{ - \pi /2}}\pi } \right)$

Comment: @JacobMayle http://math.stackexchange.com/a/439833/19379

Comment: Very nice Mahdi +1 @MahdiKhosravi

Comment: we have interesting answer, but what is the interpretation of $i^i$ ?

Comment: @Imorin: `i` raised to the power of `i`, of course. What's so special about it?

Comment: I mean a graphical interpretation.

Comment: Have fun: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \underbrace{i^{i^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^i}}}}}_n$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

$i^i=e^{i\log i}$

Now on principal branch,using $i=e^{i\pi/2}\implies \log i=i\pi/2$ gives $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$

Therefore, $i^{i^i}=i^{e^{-\pi/2}}=e^{e^{-\pi/2}\log i}=e^{i(\pi e^{-\pi/2})/2}=\cos\left(\pi \frac{e^{-\pi/2}}{2}\right)+i\sin\left(\pi \frac{e^{-\pi/2}}{2}\right)$

and hence its imaginary part is $\neq 0$ as $ \frac{e^{-\pi/2}}{2}$ is not an integer.

Comment: Don't you mean $\frac{\pi e^{-\pi/2}}{2}$ instead of $\pi e^{\frac{-\pi/2}{2}}$?

Answer (score 14):

Complex powers may have more than one value. In our case
$$ i^i=e^{i \log i}=\exp \left(i \left(\ln(1)+i \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k i\right)\right)=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k} $$ where $k$ is an integer. Thus $$i^{i^i}=e^{i^i \log(i)}=\exp\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k}\cdot\left(i \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi l i\right)\right), $$

which is $e$ to an imaginary power. It is therefore a point on the unit circle, but it can never be chosen real.

Comment: Techinically, you'd need to show that the imaginary power can't be a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you are right, but for the principal branch at least it is clear.

Comment: I'm wondering how to prove $e^{-\pi/2+2\pi k}$ is irrational?

Answer (score 10):

Wolfram Alpha gives the answer to be:

$0.94715899... + 0.320764449... i$.

Therefore it is not a real number, as the answer has an imaginary component to it.

Comment: Interesting proof.

Comment: I never said it was a proof. I was just answering the first question that was asked: is it real?

Comment: +1 I am amazed how people are still afraid of computers.

Comment: Proof by Wolfram Alpha will be a standard thing in tomorrow's mathematical world. :)

Comment: @MyUserIsThis hopefully not

Comment: http://www.smbc-comics.com/comics/20130120.gif x)

Comment: @Franklin.vp I am so afraid I shiver while typing these lines.

Comment: How can you be sure this isn't a rounding error? :P

Comment: @MTurgeon the error estimating a power series sum can be estimated.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is a fine tool if what you really want is an (approximate) answer. A question like this, nobody needs the answer, so the only goal is implicitly to *understand* the answer. The answer itself is about as useful as writing out the digits $e^\pi$ in base $7$.

Comment: @Franklin.vp Of course. But I don't see this estimate, so we can't be sure it isn't a rounding error

Comment: Wolfram didn't tell you there are lots of values, that form a dense subset of the unit circle

Comment: @LordSoth Don't be afraid. Those that know how to use computers will keep you safe from the T-800's.

Comment: It is funny how, so far, none of the 'arithmetically explicit' answers has completely proved the number is not real either. I have just a word for the detractors of this answer 'snob'.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis  That's about like arguing that a well-stocked toolbox makes an excellent architect.  The point of making a solid proof is to demonstrate an _argument_ for the validity of a proposition.  Computer software has as much comprehension of the mathematical question as does your toaster...

Comment: @Franklin.vp: The problem is not with using computers per se but with rigor. I don't see any problem with computer verified proof. I don't see any problem with computer generated proof with steps shown. I do see a problem with black box proof - especially given as an standalone answer (sure - possibly you could give a man a fish...). As for numerical solutions - they are used a) usually when analytical answer is too hard to obtain and b) verifying that you are really getting what you want and you don't have too much rounding errors.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I thought the :) at the end left it completely clear that it was a joke. Take it easy.

Comment: @MyUserIsThis  Sorry for missing the smilie: unfortunately, one does hear a bit too much about relying on computational "assistance".  We see plenty of problems here (and at other sites) where Mathematica and other "devices" really drop the ball.  (I also encounter too many students who seem to feel that electronics and software can substitute for thought.)  I apologize for perhaps thinking your statement _wasn't_ sarcasm.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing approximate or numerical about the answer that Wolfram Alpha gives: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=i%5E(i%5Ei) It's the same as the most upvoted answer. So I really don't get what problem people have.

Answer (score 7):

We have $i^i=(e^{i\pi /2})^i=e^{-\pi /2}$. Then, $$i^{i^i}=i^{e^{-\pi /2}}=(e^{-i\pi /2})^{e^{-\pi /2}}=e^{-i\pi e^{-\pi /2}/2}=\cos (\pi e^{-\pi /2}/2)-i\sin(\pi e^{-\pi /2}/2) $$ Now $\sin(\pi e^{-\pi /2}/2)$ is non-zero, since $e^{-\pi /2}/2$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 5):

First find all the values of $i^i$.  Then, if $\beta$ is one of those values, a possible value of $i^{i^i}$ is $(e^{i\pi/2})^{\beta}$.  Or $(e^{-3i\pi/2})^{\beta}$.