# Find the value of $\large i^{i^{.^{.^.}}}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Find the value of $\large i^{i^{.^{.^.}}}$ ?

How should we start to solve it ?

Also you can see [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439820/is-large-iii-real-how-can-we-compute-it) if it helps.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: If there is a solution $x$, it has the property $i^x=x$

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi: Are rast migam. :) Emtehan kon albate khode man ham jozweshun hastama chon untor soalato ghablan ha didam. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $z=i^{i^{.^{.^{.}}}}$. Then, as Hagen von Eitzen pointed out, $i^{z}=z$. Then $1=z\,i^{-z}=z \, e^{-i\pi z/2} $. It follows that 
$$-\frac{i\pi}{2}=-\frac{i\pi z}{2}\,e^{-i\pi z/2}.$$
Using the notion of [Lambert's W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), we see that 
$$-\frac{i\pi z}{2}=W(-i\pi/2),$$
or
$$z=\frac{2i}{\pi}\,W(-i\pi /2).$$

Comment: Just gonna do that. Nice answer.

Comment: Now, is this a solution? That is, does $i,i^i,i^{i^i},\dots$ converge, so $z$ exists?

Comment: Just because $z=x^z$ exists doesn't mean that it makes sense that $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}=z$.

Comment: Since $i$ is not simply just $\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ but also given by $\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi i\right)$, shouldn't there be a family of fixed points?

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: Is it true that $\left|a^{b}\right| \le |a|^{|b|}$? If so, it seems to me that the sequence $y_{0}=i, y_{n+1}=y_{n}^{i}$ is bounded. If bounded, then it must converge.

Comment: @Adrian Keister: following journals proved tower is convergence    [Convergence of infinite exponentials with complex elements](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-06/S0002-9939-1957-0096054-X/S0002-9939-1957-0096054-X.pdf) .[On the convergence of infinite exponentials](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-05/S0002-9939-1962-0141910-9/S0002-9939-1962-0141910-9.pdf)

Comment: @Maisam Hedyelloo: Do those apply? Because $|\log(i)|=\pi/2>e^{-1}$, it seems to me, does not satisfy the 'if' part of those theorems.

Answer (score 4):

by maple its possible  prove this tower is  convergence but its numerically proof

[image]

Comment: This is interesting as a "proof."