# What is the principal value of $i^{i^i}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find the principal value of $i^{i^i}$

I tried the following:
$e^{(i^i)*log(i)}$=$e^{(i^i)*i*(\pi/2+k*2/pi)}$=$e^{(i^{i+1})*(\pi/2+k*2/pi)}$=$e^{(1/2 *i* e^{(-π/2)} π)}$

I don't understand how to get the principal value from this. Or is my approach not correct?

Comment: See [Find the value of $\space\large i^{i^i}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439820/find-the-value-of-space-large-iii).

Answer (score 1):

First,

$$i^i=e^{i\,\text{Log}\, i}=e^{i\left(\log 1+i\frac\pi2\right)}=e^{-\pi/2}$$

Now,

$$i^{i^i}=e^{i^i\,\text{Log}\,i}=e^{e^{-\pi/2}\cdot\,i\pi/2}=e^{\frac{\pi e^{-\pi/2}}2i}$$

All we ha ve to check now is whether $\;\frac{\pi e^{-\pi/2}}2\in (-\pi,\,\pi)\;$ , but this is easy, either by pure algebraic evaluation or by means of using a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact $i=e^{\ln i}$ and $\ln i=i\frac{\pi}{2}$ . Can you go from here$?$